# Pandas: convert each row to a <column name,row value> dict and add as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply

I have a df such that

```
          STATUS_ID               STATUS_NM
0                 1                A
1                 2                B
2                 3                C
3                 4                D
```

I want to perform a row by apply to get a key, value par for each row in a separate column. The final df should be

```
                        STATUS
0                 {STATUS_ID:1,STATUS_NM:A}
1                 {STATUS_ID:2,STATUS_NM:B}
2                 {STATUS_ID:3,STATUS_NM:C}
3                 {STATUS_ID:4,STATUS_NM:D}
```

UPDATE:
I have tried `df[cols].apply(pd.Series.to_dict, axis=1)` and `df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(), axis=1)` but instead of getting the actual dict, I get 
`<built-in method values of dict object at 0x00...`

**I believe its my version of pandas that is causing the issue. This has been discussed here -  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8735
So the question is if there's another way to perform the same operation circumventing this issue. I cannot update my Pandas version to 0.17**

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Defining a dictionary? Getting each row from the table? Adding a new column? Removing the old columns? Try to be as specific as possible in your question so that we can be of help.

Comment: Please see my updates. Thanks

Comment: @Fizi I added an explicit loop solution. Please check.

Comment: @ayhan thanks. i was actually trying to get away from iterating over rows and hence my question. But there seems to be no way of doing it without updating my pandas version. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

```
df['STATUS'] = df.apply(pd.Series.to_dict, axis=1)

df
Out: 
   STATUS_ID STATUS_NM                              STATUS
0          1         A  {'STATUS_NM': 'A', 'STATUS_ID': 1}
1          2         B  {'STATUS_NM': 'B', 'STATUS_ID': 2}
2          3         C  {'STATUS_NM': 'C', 'STATUS_ID': 3}
3          4         D  {'STATUS_NM': 'D', 'STATUS_ID': 4}
```

If in your real DataFrame you have other columns too, you may need to specify the columns you want to have in the dictionary.

```
cols = ['STATUS_ID', 'STATUS_NM']
df['STATUS'] = df[cols].apply(pd.Series.to_dict, axis=1)
```

An alternative would be iterating over the DataFrame:

```
lst = []
for _, row in df[cols].iterrows():
    lst.append({col: row[col] for col in cols})
```

This creates a list:

```
[{'STATUS_ID': 1, 'STATUS_NM': 'A'},
 {'STATUS_ID': 2, 'STATUS_NM': 'B'},
 {'STATUS_ID': 3, 'STATUS_NM': 'C'},
 {'STATUS_ID': 4, 'STATUS_NM': 'D'}]
```

You can directly assign this to your DataFrame:

```
df['STATUS'] = lst
```

Comment: for some odd reason when I do this operation I get <built-in method values of dict object at 0x00... instead of the actual values. This is what I have been struggling with. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Fizi Can you post the code that produced those values?

Comment: I cannot due to proprietary reasons but if the code provided here should work then I'll look into what's causing mine to not work